# jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jquery slideshow, the slide show has .click function, so basically if I click on the arrows it'll take me to the next slide or the previous, but I need to make it slide automatically if no one clicks, so I was just wondering if I can use a if statement so look if its clicked move to next slide if not do it automatically in 5 seconds,

thanks for the help

```
// Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  jQuery('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
      currentPosition = (jQuery(this).attr('id')=='right_arrow')
    ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

      // Hide / show controls
      manageControls(currentPosition);
      // Move slideInner using margin-left

      jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
      });
    });

    var interval = setInterval(function() {

    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
      });   
  },5000);

    currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;

    //clear the interval
    clear();

  function clear() {
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1) {
        clearInterval(interval);    
    }
   }

  // manageControls: Hides and shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ jQuery('#left_arrow').hide() }
    else{ jQuery('#left_arrow').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ jQuery('#right_arrow').hide() }
    else{ jQuery('#right_arrow').show() }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use timers for this kind of things.

Example:

```
var doSlide = function(){
   //code here...
}
myTimer = setTimeout(doSlide,5000);
$('#leftarrow').add('#rightarrow').click(function(){
    //stop the timer from counting
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    //go to the next or prev slide
    doSlide();
}
```

By doing this, once a user clicks on one of the arrows, it will slide once and stop sliding automatically and allows the user to read (or see?) whatever is in the slide he got to.

By the way: to select elements with jQuery you can use the alias `$` like seen in my example.